# Is it possible to set unlimited session timeout in php

Tags: php

I have my website that need login for view further information. My problem is that when user login the session is started to a limited time that already define in php.ini file. I want to unlimited this session time when user log in. I already user ini_set() function i-e:

```
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime",720000); 
ini_set('session.gc_probability',1); 
ini_set('session.gc_divisor',1);
```

which temproraily set php_ini value of session time. but it coul'nt work.

Is there something im doing wrong?

Please help me for resolve this problem

Comment: You can store in a cookie? `setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure)` Might be a better way

Comment: "unlimited" is not possible, but `60 * 60 * 24 * 365` (`31536000`) will last you a year. Isn't that enough? `720000` seconds is only `8.3 days` (`720000 / 60 / 60 / 24`).

Comment: Have a look at this question, the accepted answer explain it in much detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960

Comment: I think you're abusing the session logic. Sessions are all about expiring sometime. Though, you can set a session to 1 year which seems, to me, an "unlimited" one.

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597176/how-to-keep-session-alive-without-reloading-page

Answer (score 1):

Set [`session.gc_probability`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) to 0 before starting the session. This will give the garbage collector a 0% chance of removing session data.
 You have to do this in all applications that share the same session storage location.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it this way:

```
<?php

 ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 30*60);
 session_start();

 ?>
```

Second parameter is **number of seconds** after which data will be seen as '*garbage*' and potentially cleaned up.

Also check [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) out for more information.

Ofcourse you can adjust numbers that suit your needs.