# Extend PHP Session timeout using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have a web page with a huge form to fill. In most cases, session time out and users lost a lot of data. I searched for this problem and found this [Prevent session expired in PHP Session for inactive user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962671/prevent-session-expired-in-php-session-for-inactive-user)

I implemenet ajax call

```
function heartbeat() {
    clearTimeout(window.intervalID);
    $.ajax({
        url:    "trash.png",
        type:   "post",
        cache:  false,            
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
        },
        complete: function() {
            window.intervalID = setTimeout(function() {
                heartbeat();    
            }, 300000); 
        }
    });
}
```

and call `heartbeat();` in `$(document).ready`, `trash.png` is in the same directory as file where I have jQuery code with Ajax.

I checked with fiddler and jQuery is sending requests to `trash.png` every 5 minutes. But after 30 minutes my session still expires.

`session_start();` is called when user log in to the web page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can not keep the session alive without calling a php script which starts a session, just downloading a png file will not keep the session from dying. Create a PHP Script like this:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Put it into the directory and call this instead of that trash.png asset.

You might need to call other things before calling `session_start()` depending on how you are starting it in your other scripts.

Comment: I updated my question. I already start session when user log in.

Comment: This won't help, the session will timeout if you do not call a php script that (re)starts the session before the timeout occurs.

Comment: And how should I restart the session? I tried sending the ajax request to image because of this post and accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962671/prevent-session-expired-in-php-session-for-inactive-user

Comment: As I already stated in my answer, create a php script called hearbeat.php put the code I show above in it, upload it to the directory where your script is and call hearbeat.php instead of trash.png

Comment: Ok I'll try this. But I'm still a bit concerned because of this from PHP docs:

`4.3.3 As of PHP 4.3.3, calling session_start() after the session was previously started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. Also, the second session start will simply be ignored.`

Comment: You really should try to learn the difference between your javascript frontend and your php backend, what you are talking about there is using `session_start()` twice in one php script. But you are running it once while your users login, then just let them use the html form - the session timeout timer will start right after the login and won't be reset until you call a php script that contains `session_start()` again.

Answer (score 0):

In ajax you can post timeout as

```
jQuery.ajax({
       url: 'ajaxhandler.php',
       success: function (result) {                               
            returned_value=result;
       },
       timeout: 10000,
       async: false
    });
```